# No feedback on file upload

Tags: cordova, ssl, https, file-transfer

I am using PhoneGap to develop a mobile that should be able to take and upload a picture. Nevertheless I do not get any feedback from my upload script (neither 'Success' or 'Fail') and the picture is not uploaded on the server when the target URL begins with http**S** (that works well with http). Nevertheless scripts I use come from the various examples I found on Stackoverflow.

Below is the code I use:

```
    $('#mr_take_picture').click(function(){
    $('#mr_take_picture').prop('disabled', true);

    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,
                            function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
                            { quality: 50, 
                            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI }
                            );
    $('#mr_take_picture').prop('disabled', false);

});

function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();

    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    options.headers = { Connection: "close" }
    options.chunkedMode = false;

    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";

    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    console.log('transfer starting');
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI('https://www.my-server.com/files/test.php'), win, fail, options);
    console.log('transfer finished');
}

function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    alert('win');
}

function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    console.log("upload error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
}
```

Below is the file test.php

`<?php
   $new_image_name = "YEAH.jpg";
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/var/www/html/files/".$new_image_name);
?>`

Below is what I can see in the phonegap console when I try to take a picture and upload it:

```
[phonegap] 200 /__api__/autoreload
[phonegap] [console.log] transfer starting
[phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1431336989085-21&sid=_Bw59PxBVBjKSpAaAAAK
[phonegap] 200 /__api__/autoreload
[phonegap] [console.log] transfer finished
[phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1431336989220-22&sid=_Bw59PxBVBjKSpAaAAAK
[phonegap] 200 /__api__/autoreload
```

As you can see it appears that the functions win and fail are never executed.. Where could the problem come from?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, it works well with http, not with httpS... I added the parameter TRUE to the ft.upload() method but this still does not work. How to deal with that?

Comment: One more precision: the SSL/TLS certificate is not "Self-signed" and use SHA-1.